# Deleting From stl map inside a map... inside a method

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

so i'm trying to implement a File-system in c++.
i have a Directory Class which holds a map.
each directory can hold inside it's map another directory (so i have a map inside a map)

i'm trying to delete a file/directory, inside the method it deletes and all is well, but the method is done my main map doesn't update...

here the relevant code:

Directory Class (implemented using Composite):

```
class Directory : public FileComponent
{
private:
std::map<std::string,FileComponent*> directoryList;
public:
std::map<std::string, FileComponent*> &getMap() {
    return directoryList;
}
```

class fileSystem:

```
private:
FileComponent* find(Mode mode, const std::string& newDirectory, const std::string& directoryName, std::map<std::string, FileComponent*> check);
std::map<std::string,FileComponent*> fileSystem;
```

};

here's what i tried to do (finding a file and copying it...)

```
void filesys::copy(const std::string& fileName, const std::string& directoryName){
//looking for file
mapitr itr = fileSystem.find(fileName);
if (itr != fileSystem.end()){
    fileSystem.erase(itr);
    //file found, looikng for directory
}
else{
    for (itr = fileSystem.begin(); itr != fileSystem.end(); itr++){
        FileComponent* toCopy = find(CopyFile, fileName, directoryName, itr->second->getMap());
        if (toCopy != nullptr)
            //found! need to copy
            break;
    }
}
```

}

and my find method:

```
FileComponent* filesys::find(Mode mode,const std::string& newDirectory, const std::string& directoryName, std::map<std::string,FileComponent*> check){
else if (mode == CopyFile){
     mapitr itr = check.find(newDirectory);
     if (itr != check.end()){
         FileComponent* toCopy = itr->second;
         check.erase(itr);
         return toCopy;
     }
     else{
         for (itr = check.begin(); itr != check.end(); itr++){
             FileComponent* toCopy;
             try{
             toCopy = find(CopyFile, newDirectory, directoryName, itr->second->getMap());
             if (toCopy != nullptr){
                 return toCopy;
             }
             }
             catch (mExceptions& e){
                 e.what();
             }

         }
         return nullptr;
     }
 }
```

}

inside the function it finds and erases and all seems to be in order... however once returning the directory/file is still inside my filesystem...
i'm returning my inside map by reference... so i really am out of ideas why it doesn't want to work...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the argument `check` (the map) by *value* to the `find` function. That means the data is *copied* and you only work on the copy and not the original. You should pass it by *reference instead:

```
std::map<std::string,FileComponent*>& check
```

---

On an unrelated note, the function name `find` is not a good name, it doesn't really describes what the function *really* does, which is find *and* erase.

Comment: stupid me... yep that sorted the problem... thanks a lot.

find is a private method which finds a file, it has different modes, and i use it for inserting as well :)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
filesys::find(Mode mode,
              const std::string& newDirectory,
              const std::string& directoryName,
              std::map<std::string, FileComponent*> check)
```

you pass `check` by value, not by reference, so you modify a copy, not the original.